# mounting external drives to a Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, nfs

I'm Dockerizing an application and I have data on an external file server. Normally, when not using Docker, I mount to my file server. Files is a directory within my docroot.

The way I'm currently set up with Docker, I'm accessing my docroot as a data volume from my container- the official version is on my host system. I'm not sure what the best way to access file server. Should I set somehow set up NFS in my container? use a plugin?

Comment: Good question. I think a "normal" Docker cannot mount filesystems. It needs special privileges. And even if you mount from within Docker, will the mount be hidden from the rest of the system (other processes on the host)?